# Mongo DB sort by date and group by tag

Tags: mongodb, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo DB collection similar to this:

```
{
    "_id": "...",
    "name": "name 1",
    "created": "2020-07-21T08:11:18.414+00:00",
    "tags": ["red", "green"]
}
{
    "_id": "...",
    "name": "name 2",
    "created": "2020-07-20T08:11:18.414+00:00",
    "tags": ["red", "blue"]
}
{
    "_id": "...",
    "name": "name 3",
    "created": "2020-07-19T08:11:18.414+00:00",
    "tags": ["green", "blue"]
}
{
    "_id": "...",
    "name": "name 4",
    "created": "2020-07-18T08:11:18.414+00:00",
    "tags": ["white", "blue"]
}
{
    "_id": "...",
    "name": "name 5",
    "created": "2020-07-17T08:11:18.414+00:00",
    "tags": ["white", "green"]
}
```

I need to be able to specify a list of tags, and, for each tag in the list, I need to fetch the most recently created document. In the example above, if I specify `["red", "green", "blue"]`, I should get a result similar to this:

```
{
    "red": {
        "_id": "...",
        "name": "name 1",
        "created": "2020-07-21T08:11:18.414+00:00",
        "tags": ["red", "green"]
    },
    "green": {
        "_id": "...",
        "name": "name 1",
        "created": "2020-07-21T08:11:18.414+00:00",
        "tags": ["red", "green"]
    },
    "blue": {
        "_id": "...",
        "name": "name 2",
        "created": "2020-07-20T08:11:18.414+00:00",
        "tags": ["red", "blue"]
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. What would be the best Mongo DB query to obtain the above result?
2. If there are any skilled Spring Data experts around, how would it be translated into a Spring Data query, probably using an `AggregationOperation`?

I would be happy with a good answer to question 1, and I can look for an answer to question 2 separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can achieve this with aggregations

1. `$sort` the *created* to order by descending
2. `$facet` helps to categories the inner documents where we use `$match` to filter *tags*
3. `$project` helps for projection. We already sorted by *created*. So we will get the first element by `$arrayElemAt`, Sometimes if there is no element, it will throw an exception, so just to return empty object, we use `$ifNull`

Mongo script

```
[
  {
    $sort: {
      created: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      red: [
        {
          $match: {
            tags: "red"
          }
        }
      ],
      green: [
        {
          $match: {
            tags: "green"
          }
        }
      ],
      blue: [
        {
          $match: {
            tags: "blue"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      red: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$red",
              0
            ]
          },
          {}
        ]
      },
      blue: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$blue",
              0
            ]
          },
          {}
        ]
      },
      green: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$green",
              0
            ]
          },
          {}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CD0IlJZsZan)**

When we convert this into Spring-data

```
public List<Object> test() {
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created"),
            facet(
                    match(Criteria.where("tags").is("red"))
            ).as("red")
                    .and(
                            match(Criteria.where("tags").is("green"))
                    ).as("green")
                    .and(
                            match(Criteria.where("tags").is("blue"))
                    ).as("blue"),
            project()
                    .and(ConditionalOperators.ifNull(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("red").elementAt(0)).then(new Document())).as("red")
                    .and(ConditionalOperators.ifNull(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("blue").elementAt(0)).then(new Document())).as("blue")
                    .and(ConditionalOperators.ifNull(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("green").elementAt(0)).then(new Document())).as("green")

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

Note : I haven't tested the above code in spring-boot. But it was written based on working mongo script. Hope it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it and let you know

Comment: i am alao looking for the same. Please share if you get success to this solution.

Comment: @varman tested successfully (including the java code), thanks